# "OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted" error when downloading Pandas on macOS

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried installing Pandas on macOS. 
It first tries to install Numpy, says

Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1

```
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:


Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/8y/lq4gsyx97_q171qrh2q18z0h0000gn/T/pip-9NwJUf-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Then fails to install Pandas. "pip list" shows numpy (1.8.0rc1) has been installed.

Thanks for the help.

[When I use sudo, this happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAnpw.png)

Comment: SIP is probably blocking you from installing into `/System/Library`.

Comment: How do I fix the SIP thing?

Comment: https://www.imore.com/el-capitan-system-integrity-protection-helps-keep-malware-away

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to run `pip` as `super user` or a system user that has the permission to write to `Python package site` directory;
I don't own a `mac` but I think the general course of action for you will be to try to install `pandas` as `root` like this:

```
sudo pip install -U pandas
```

Comment: If this were the problem I think he'd get "Permission denied", not "Operation not permitted".

Comment: sudo didn't work. I just edited my initial post with the error Sudo gave.

Comment: Running `pip3 install pandas` worked. Thanks for the help.